# SQL: How to get recent record

Tags: sql, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

I need help. How do I get the most recent record for two separate tables?
Table 1 is Employee Record Table with Employee Number and Employee Name in it.
Table 2 is Address Table with Employee Number, Address 1, Address 2, County, City, Country, Postal Code, and Effective Date.

How do I get the recent data from the two tables based on the on most recent date?

Sadly, my SQL doesn't work. Somehow I get an error "Incorrect Syntax Near 'T3'". I couldn't figure out what is that incorrect syntax. Please help. Thank you!

```
SELECT  T1.EmpNumber,
        T1.EmpName,
        T2.City,
        T2.Country,
        T2.EffDate

FROM    EmployeeTable T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AddressTable T2
        ON T1.EmpNumber = T2.EmpNumber
        AND T2.EffDate = (
                 SELECT EmpNumber,
                        MAX (EffDate) as RecentDate
                 FROM AddressTable
                 GROUP BY EmpNumber) T3 ON T1.EmpNumber = T3.EmpNumber AND T2.EffDate = T3.RecentDate
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: sql-server, mysql, postgresql...?

Comment: `AND T2.EffDate = ( SELECT EmpNumber, MAX(EffDate) as RecentDate ...` How do you expect your code to work?  You are trying to test an equality with table.

Answer (score 1):

A portable solution to this greatest-n-per-group problem is to filter with a subquery - this is also in the spirit of your attempt:

```
select e.employee_name, a.*
from  EmployeeTable e
inner join AddressTable a on a.employee_number = e.employee_number
where a.effective_date = (
    select max(a1.effective_date) 
    from AddressTable a1 
    where a1.employee_number = e.employee_number
)
```

If you want to allow employees that have no adresses, then you can put the filtering in the `on` clause of a `left join`:

```
select e.employee_name, a.*
from  EmployeeTable e
left join AddressTable a 
    on  a.employee_number = e.employee_number
    and a.effective_date = (
        select max(a1.effective_date) 
        from AddressTable a1 
        where a1.employee_number = e.employee_number
    )
```